# Databinding validation does not catch exceptions

Tags: validation, silverlight-5.0

I bound a textbox to an object in memory that throws an exception when a wrong value is entered.

If the TextBox has ValidatesOnException set to true and Mode=TwoWay, then if an exception should occur it should be intercepted by the Binding, but it's not.

The TextBox looks like:

```
    <TextBox Name="txtAge"
             Text="{Binding Age, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"
              />
```

I created an object in memory and set the layoutroot grid's DataContext to the created object in the UserControl's constructor.

```
Student std = new Student();
LayoutRoot.DataContext = std;
```

The bound object type is:

```
public class Student {

   private string _name;
   public string Name {
       get { return _name; }
       set { _name = value; }
   }

   private int _age;
   public int Age {
       get { return _age; }
       set {
           if (value > 100 || value < 0) {
               throw new Exception("Please enter age between 0 - 100");
           }
           _age = value;
       }
   }
}
```

The exception thrown by the property Age when a number < 0 or > 100 is entered should be intercepted.

This is the behavior I expect:

[image: image1]

But I get the exception instead.

I'm studying validation with this blog I found http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/86955/Silverlight-4-Data-Validation-Tip-of-the-Day-Part

This is step 8, this should be the behavior, the author explains NotifyOnValidationError and BindingValidationError beyond this step.

What setting could I be failing to make?

Thanks in advance,

Rafael

Comment: Moreover, I opened the solution with VS2012 and ran it from there, and it worked!

I opened it with VS2010 afterwards, ran it, and the exception still appears.

What setting could I be missing in VS2010?

Comment: Have you tried clicking Continue when the exception window appeared on the screen, rather than Stop?

Comment: @Alyce I had a similar issue and I followed your advice on clicking Continue and then it displays the message. As a matter of fact, while searching for the solution I read somewhere that this was OK as I was in debug mode and it will work fine in release mode. Still not sure how is this possible but can you please confirm if thats what you meant?

Comment: Yeah, according to [this article](http://jeffhandley.com/archive/2009/04/01/184.aspx), "if you run the application outside of the debugger, everything will work as you want."

Answer (score 0):

You could disable breaking on all user-unhandled exceptions, or just add the exception to the list of exceptions not to break on (from [here](http://jeffhandley.com/archive/2009/04/01/184.aspx))

Go to Debug -> Exceptions -> and uncheck the exception, i.e. 
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotation.ValidationException

Or, from a comment [here](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Data-Validation-in-Silverlight-3.aspx), apply the `[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerHidden()]` attribute on the property. 
("Notice that you may still get the VS Just-in-Time Debugger dialog asking you whether you want to debug it.")